# How to get date from month as input in oracle?

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic

My query is , I need to give input a month ,i.e ex :input will be 'MAR' then i need to get 1st date and last date for the March month .

```
select to_char(trunc(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'MM'),'DD-MON-YYYY') "First Day of Last Month"
       , to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') ,'DD-MON-YYYY') "Last Day of Last Month"
 from dual ;
```

Any one please help..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Last dateof month using pl/sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20680985/last-dateof-month-using-pl-sql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
month_start := to_date('MAR', 'MON');
month_end := last_day(month_start);
```

- Month names depend on specifics of the NLS language/territory so may need to tweak them. (alter session set nls_language/nls_territory = AMERICAN/AMERICA).
- You haven't mentioned what would be the year, so the assumption is that you need current one.

If the year is also a variable input:

```
month_start := to_date('2015-MAR', 'yyyy-MON');
```

Comment: Thank u , so if we want for specific year ??

Comment: for specific year, e.g.: `to_date('2013-SEP', 'yyyy-MON')`

Comment: @kartik, if you can agree on having numeric month instead of name (e.g. 03 instead of MAR): that would prevent the mentioned NLS hassle.